# Block editing of possible duplicate text?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Is this a new feature? I discovered today that you can edit the text accompanying the "Possible Duplicate" box. This should be prevented unless you are a Moderator. It could result in the loss of key linked information. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367433/post-increment-and-pre-increment) (I rolled back the change). Doesn't seem right to me since you have to VOTE on what possible duplicates to include with the question. By editing, you are taking away that vote.

Comment: @Mysticial: Seems like the system is broken then.. one vote constitutes a possible duplicate?

Comment: @0A0D: Well, it says **possible**. If 5 users vote for 5 different questions, what options do you have except listing all of them?

Comment: @Dennis: I see your point. My point is there is a system for voting for duplicates and that works. We don't arbitrarily edit posts to add the possible duplicate box, so why stray from that by editing? Vote to reopen or flag it. Seems a little weighted too much to one side.

Comment: @0A0D The problem is, if four voters vote to close as an exact duplicate of a question that is one, and one voter fat-fingers and chooses a non-dupe, reopening the question just to reclose as duplicate seems pointless. Leaving the non-dupe as possible dupe is bad too. So what should be done? Restrict editing of possible dupe links to 20k users perhaps, that might have a fighting chance of preventing invalid edits to those links.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I see your point too. It's the arbitrary decision. That's why we vote, its the system that is broken IMHO. Sure we can raise the bar, but when you vote to close via committee the bar is supposed to be raised because you have more eyes on. Some people say the revision history is there, so what does it matter? Not everyone is going to look at that.

Answer (score 0):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). It allows removing a link from the "possible duplicate" section in the event that there are several, but the question isn't a duplicate of one of them.

Comment: Manually removing the duplicate link is bad practice: It leaves the questions closed as exact duplicate, just without the link. If it really isn't a duplicate, it should get reopened properly or closed for some other reason.

Comment: @Dennis What was removed was **one** link, and one that isn't a dupe. The link to the **real** dupe was still there. IOW, with the edit, the Internet is a better place.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: That sounds reasonable. Since this answer is CW now, I'll clarify it.

Comment: @Dennis you could have edited it even before it was CW :-P